# How to get the font style of a cell field of excel in Java, Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, fonts, apache-poi

I would like to capture the font of a cell field in excel in Java. I am using Apache POI. If possible, I would like to capture `font-color`, `font-family`, `font-weight`, `font-size`, etc.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

**Edited based on comment**

You can refer to [XSSFCellStyle](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html), from it you can get the [XSSFFont](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFont.html). Using that you can get [XSSFColor](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html), [getFontName()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFont.html#getFontName()) or [getFamily()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFont.html#getFamily()) and [getFontHeight()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFont.html#getFontHeight()) or [getFontHeightInPoints()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFont.html#getFontHeightInPoints()).

Based on example cell that I've used:

```
XSSFCellStyle cs = cell.getCellStyle();
XSSFFont font = cs.getFont();

//Getting Font color
XSSFColor color = font.getXSSFColor();
System.out.println("Font color : " + color.getARGBHex());
//==>   FF00B0F0

//Getting Font name
System.out.println("Font name : " + font.getFontName());
//==>   Arial

//Getting Font family name
FontFamily family = FontFamily.valueOf(((XSSFFont) font).getFamily());
System.out.println("Font family : " + family);
//==>   SWISS

//Getting Font family int
System.out.println("Font family in int : " + font.getFamily());
//==>   2

//Getting Font height
System.out.println("Font FontHeight : " + font.getFontHeight());
//==>   280

//Getting Font height in point
System.out.println("Font height in point : " + font.getFontHeightInPoints());
//==>   14

//Getting Font bold weight  
System.out.println("Font BoldWeight : " + font.getBoldweight());
//==>   700
```

Comment: I can get the CSSFColor using this, but other properties like FontName, family, fontweight can't be captured using this

Answer (score 0):

I have it in Groovy but the principle should be similar:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*
import java.io.*

InputStream file = new FileInputStream('C:\\Folder\\File.xls')
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file)
Sheet sheet1 = wb.getSheet('Sheet1')
// to get first row
Row row = sheet1.getRow(0)
// to get first cell
Cell cell = row.getCell(0)
// to get its style
HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle()
// to get font
HSSFFont cellFont = cellStyle.getFont(wb)
// to get font name as text
String cellFontName = cellFont.getFontName()
```